# How to get table columns next to each other and move down once container width reached

Tags: html, css

I'm generating a product list using php and tables however it currently looks like this:

[image]

Where each item is displayed under the previous one. I'm trying to get it so the each product is displayed next to each other, and once it reaches the containers width it goes to the next line.

I'm not sure if using table is correct method but I'm pretty new at this and I'm not sure what else I could use. Could someone point me into the right direction.

Here's part of the code that is generating the products in my php:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>
            <td><img src='$row[imagepath]' width='225' height'150' /></td>
            </br>
            <td>$row[name]</td>
            <div class='textwrap' ><td>$row[description]</td></div>
            <td>£$row[price]</td>
            <form action='basket.php' method='post'>
                <input type='submit' value='Add to basket' name='$row[pid]' />
            </form>
        </tr>";
}
      echo "</table>";
```

Heres relevant CSS code too:

```
.products{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.textwrap{
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    width: 225px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: heres a good tutorial on html5/css3 columns if youre able to utilise that. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-html5css3-columns-for-all-browsers

Comment: you're adding a new row with each echo... Place the `<tr>` outside the echo and they'll sit side by side.

Comment: oops... rather wrap the echo with the '<tr>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table element is, strictly speaking, for tabular data, I would see this more as a list of products and as such would mark up something like this:

```
<ul class="products">
<?php $i=0; for each($products as $product { $i++; ?>
  <li class="products__single <?php if($i %4 = 0){ echo 'last'} ?>">
    <span class="image"><?php //echo image here ?></span>
    <span class="title"><?php //echo title here ?></span>
    <span class="description"><?php //echo description here ?></span>
    <span class="price"><?php//echo price here ?></span>
  </li>
<?php } //end for each loop ?>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.products__single {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 2.66%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.products__single.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media all and(max-width: 600px) {
  .products__single {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

The $i variable is simply to enable us to add a last class on every fifth element preventing the margin-right from breaking the layout.

Then below a given width the media query kicks in and reduces the number of columns to 1.

I haven't tested this but it should be pretty close to what you want.